# Linhas com dois itens de acordo com o tamanho da tela, é possivel?

Tags: css, react-native, flexbox

Minha intenção é ter linhas com dois itens, e estes itens devem ter uma largura de acordo com o tamanho da tela, ou seja, tela de 500 , calculo `500/2 - espaços`.

Seria algo parecido com isso.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu código:

```
const columns = 2;
const margin = vw(1);
const spacing = (columns + 1) / columns * margin;
function vw(percentageWidth) {
  return Dimensions.get('window').width * (percentageWidth / 100);
}

export default class SearchPesquisa extends Component {
  cards () {
    return this.props.produtos.map((item, indice) => {
      return(
        <View key={i} style={styles.cell}>
            <Card>
              <CardItem style={{ height: 280, borderRadius: 4 }}>
              </CardItem>
            </Card>
        </View>
      )
      })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ScrollView>
          { this.cards() }
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
    justifyContent: 'flex-start'
  },
  cell: {
    width: vw(100) / columns - spacing
  }
});
```

Explicando:

- `flexDirection:'row'` direção de exibição dos meus itens.
- `columns` número de colunas a ser exibido.
- `vw` calculo de porcentagem da margen, no exemplo `vw(1)` será 1 porcento
- `spacing` apenas um espaço.

Meu exemplo:
ViewPort: ~411, Margin: ~4.11, Spacing: ~6.17, WidCard:199.54

Problema: Cada card está ficando em um linha.

Comment: Um exemplo apenas em CSS/HTML te ajudaria?

Comment: @hugocsl não sei, será que consigo aplicar ele por aqui? Coloca ai que te aviso se deu certo :)

Comment: Seus cards vão ter uma largura fixa? O container que os cardas estão dentro vai ter uma largura definida?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meu problema está relacionado nessa parte:

```
     <View style={styles.container}>
        <ScrollView>
          { this.cards() }
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
```

Modifiquei para:

```
      <ScrollView>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          { this.cards() }
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
```

Vejam que no primeiro código o filho direto do `container` é um `ScroolView` e só tem ele, caso outro elemento fosse adicionado, este ficaria ao lado devido a direção do alinhamento definido como `row`.

Já o segundo elemento eu tenho várias `View` feitas dinâmicamente de acordo com os itens do meu array. Como eu tenho um valor fixo para cada `View`, as próximas View não iriam caber na mesma row, forçando assim uma quebra.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Teste extends Component {
....
<View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
    <ScrollView style={{
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
        alignContent: 'center'
    }}>
    {_renderExample()}
    </ScrollView>

</View>
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Teste usando 50%:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
    justifyContent: 'flex-start'
  },
  cell: {
    width: 50%
  }
});
```